# Save Media without using MediaService

Tags: .net, umbraco, umbraco7

Is there a way to save an Image (located in the server) and save it in the Media without using the MediaService?

The reason for this is because I have a background process running using Hangfire then when I try to use MediaService and save it I'm getting an error `Value null exception: HttpContext` since background service doesn't have a HTTPContext it's throwing an error. I implemented a fake HttpContext and it work great for smaller size. But for bigger size it throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Now I was thinking what if I just manually save it in the DB without using `MediaService.Save()` because I notice that when I run the code `media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);` it automatically moves the file into the `media` folder and assigns an ID to that. But the only concern is it doesn't appear in the CMS/Media page unless you execute `MediaService.Save()` which also gives me out of memoryexception.

Now I tried to run `MediaService.Save()` on page load and it was working very fast and I was able to save the file and display it in the media page. But since that is only a once time process I really need that function to be in a background process. But when I run it in background process it give HttpContext Error and when I try to Fake the HttpContext Error it's giving me outofmemory exception.

So now I'm only left with thinking what if I save it's value to the DB. Much like I'll try to run MediaService.Save() on my own code that way I will only need to save the ID and the values need to make it display in the Media page.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, with your recent line of questions on here, it sounds to me as if you are using the wrong tool for whatever job you are trying to get done :-/ I'd love to know *why* you're trying to do what you are doing - why can't the videos be on Youtube or Vimeo or ThwentyThree or something else? Context would allow us to be more constructively helpful, I think.

Remember that Umbraco is a CMS first and foremost, not a DAM. It can totally do some DAM stuff, but ... it's a CMS. Have you for instance considered using Azure Blob Storage to store those big files of yours instead? There's an Umbraco plugin for that, which allows you to save files outside the Umbraco installation - but I don't know if it'll even help in this scenario: https://our.umbraco.com/packages/collaboration/umbracofilesystemprovidersazure/

I know it's not an answer to your question, sorry.

Comment: Definitely appreciate your answer @Jannik Anker. The reason behind why I used umbraco to store this large file is because client have private files (not just videos) that they want to store in our db hence they don't want to use other third party site. The reason why I didn't use Azure Blob is first I'm not familiar with it second is the Live site is not using Azure but we are using Private Dedicated Server in AWS. Hence I cannot fully make use of Azure capabilities but is tied up in using Umbraco Media

Comment: Good :-) I'm wondering if it might be worth to try and make a FilesystemProvider for something like S3 or EFS (https://aws.amazon.com/efs/?nc2=h_mo) instead of the route you are currently trying to take? I mean, it's causing nothing but trouble and you are, as I said, seemingly trying to use a screwdriver to do a hammers job. Or however you might put it :-/ Of course it depends on internal policy as well.

Comment: You could take a look at https://github.com/jacexor/Umbraco8-Simple-AWS-S3 (check the original project for more details) and see if it makes any sense for you :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If ever I will be implementing this do I need to use MediaService to make the uploaded file appear in the Media page? Becase the mediaservice.set_value moves my asset from my `upload` folder to the media folder now the only way to make it appear in the media page is to use MediaService.Save() but this throws an error as it's setting an HTTP request. I would assume that if I use the link it will save the image to the S3 but should I also use the MediaService?

Comment: Yes, I believe your "flow" will be the same, but inside the MediaService it'll save your files elsewhere (S3/Azure/whatever). And if that "elsewhere" is designed for storing static files I'm thinking the timeouts and file size limits should be drastically different than on a website. It's surely worth a quick test? Install a fresh Umbraco and the S3 provider, create an account on S3 (shouldn't be too expensive for a few tests) and try uploading a few of your outlandishly large files ;-) I'm not even sure you need to use your upload folder as an in between thing then, just try it "plain"?